# hostapd & dnsmasq Obtaining IP forever

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, dnsmasq, hostapd

I'm trying to set up a wireless access point using `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` but I can't get it to work.

The AP works, but when I try to connect to it gets stuck on "Obtaining IP address". I see the connection in the `hostapd` console, but nothing happens in the `dnsmasq` one.

Here are my configs, commands and their outputs:

```
#: dnsmasq -C dnsmasq.conf -H hosts.conf -d -q

dnsmasq: started, version 2.68 cachesize 150
dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCP, IP range 10.0.0.10 -- 10.0.0.250, lease time 12h
dnsmasq: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
dnsmasq: read /etc/hosts - 5 addresses
dnsmasq: read hosts.conf - 1 addresses
```

dnsmasq.conf:

```
no-resolv
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10,10.0.0.250,12h
server=8.8.8.8
log-queries
log-dhcp
```

hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=Test
channel=1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I didn't open the DHCP port in my firewall (67).

```
#: ufw allow 67
```

Comment: This was driving me nuts until I found your post. Would also add that you need to add outbound to port 68 if your firewal is super restrictive (like mine was).